# WWAN support in Lenovo Thinkpad T14 Gen 1

Tags: thinkpad, mobile-broadband, wwan

I bought a new Lenovo Thinkpad T14 Gen 1 with a nano sim card reader from the rear.
I inserted a nano sim card but seems to be not detected.
Can anyone tell me how to check whether WWAN is supported in this laptop, and how to check if sim card is detected.
I am using Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the sim card? Just read from it? Boot from it? As for whether the hardware is supported that would be a question for the manufacture of the hardware.

Comment: A sim card to access LTE network.

Comment: I would think you would need a driver for that.

Comment: @David: Now I realize your question. There is no driver for it but it is under active development https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/T15-20S6-Infrared-emitter/m-p/5041989?page=1#5156828 . Hope it'll be released someday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `lspci` and look for cards that looks like a 4G/LTE card. A combination of google and some guesswork is likely needed, as there's many different vendors of such cards.

Many laptops come with sim card slot, but no wwan card. Usually in these cases you can install a wwan card in a slot on the mainboard.

Comment: I ran lspci but no 4G/LTE card. can I conclude that motherboard has no wwan card?

Comment: Yes, probably. You can open your laptop and check if there's wiring for antenna. In that case you can get a card from e.g. ebay.

Comment: thank you very much.