# WWAN T14S Support, Modem-manager can't find modem

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, thinkpad, lspci, wwan

I have a Thinkpad T14s (AMD) with the WWAN card offered directly by Lenovo.
Modem manager can't seem to detect the card though?

(Ubuntu 22.04)

having seen [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328565/wwan-support-in-lenovo-thinkpad-t14-gen-1), I ran `lspci` which returned:
`05:00.0 Wireless controller [0d40]: Intel Corporation XMM7360 LTE Advanced Modem (rev 01)`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.7 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.1 Serial controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111xP UART #1 (rev 0e)
02:00.2 Serial controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111xP UART #2 (rev 0e)
02:00.3 IPMI Interface: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111xP IPMI interface (rev 0e)
02:00.4 USB controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL811x EHCI host controller (rev 0e)
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
05:00.0 Wireless controller [0d40]: Intel Corporation XMM7360 LTE Advanced Modem (rev 01)
06:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev d3)
07:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
07:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
07:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
07:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
07:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
07:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

However, when I run 'Modem-Manager GUI' I get a blank screen,
and when I run 'mmcli' I get 'No modems were found'.

I'm about 3 years deep into Linux but this is my first time working with WWAN laptop stuff so don't know where to go from here.

I do also see from [this post](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Fedora-on-X1-Extreme-Gen-3-WWAN-Fibocom-L860-GL-4G-LTE-Advanced-Cat-16-not-working/m-p/5044699?page=4) that I'm at least not struggling alone, though I'm not sure if there's anything more recent that I'm missing. I do also note that other posts on a similar vein are talking about using usb modems rather than internal cards, not sure if theres a practical difference.

Comment: Hello. Seems that device may need its own driver. Have you searched for that? Asked the maker?

Comment: @David I can't seem to find drivers anywhere, I see some hints at there being some for windows 10 but as I'm not dualbooting that doesn't help me

Comment: It would not help if you were. Windows drivers do not work in Ubuntu and a driver in Windows has no effect on any other OS.

Answer (score 0):

The  Fibocom L850-GL / Intel XMM7360 WWAN card didn't work out of the box or with any support from Lenovo on my Thinkpad.

There are reports of people having success with the WWAN card using a un-official [project on GitHub by abrasive](https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci). I got my card working a couple of years back in time, but only manually loading drivers, and it wasn't reliable for a work setting.